# Set mouspointer if you login via startx

Tags: xorg

I recently purged my lightdm and login to my xmonad session via startx. This works very well except that the mouse pointer is sometimes a black cross (for example if it is on an empty workspace, or when clicking and holding on a empty place in the firefox menu-panel).

When using lightdm this problem didn't occur.

How can I configure the mouse-pointer in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `xsetroot -cursor_name arrow` in my ~/.xinitrc.